# Как получить результат поиска по частям (страну, город, поселок, улица, дом и т.д.) в YandexMapsMobile?

Tags: swift, yandex-maps-api

С помощью YMKSearchSuggestSession я получаю [YMKSuggestItem], но в свойствах элемента нахожу только displyaText, который хранить обобщенные данные в одной строке, а мне нужен детальный элемент с разделением на страну, город, улицу и т.д.

```
var searchManager: YMKSearchManager?
var suggestSession: YMKSearchSuggestSession!

func setup() {
    searchManager = YMKSearch.sharedInstance().createSearchManager(with: .combined)
    suggestSession = searchManager?.createSuggestSession()

    suggestSession.suggest(withText: textField.text,
                           window: BOUNDING_BOX,
                           suggestOptions: YMKSuggestOptions()) { response, error in
        if let items = response {
            //items.first.displayText
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Саджест никогда не позиционировался Яндексом как полноценный поиск. Он должен лишь помогать ввести адрес, который затем следует нормально геокодировать. Вот в ответе геокодера уже будут структурированные данные, которые вам нужны. Посмотрите статью Яндекса на Хабре по особенностям поиска в MapKit:
https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/428564/